# How to exclude one row from sort by column on QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: qt, sorting, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm using QTableView with QSortFilterProxyModel.

I have emty row for manually input:

Example of table

[image]

Now i want to sort by Date

But i don't wanna move the last row

Example of sort table

[image]

I will be grateful for the help

```
proxyModel->sort(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom QSortFilterProxyModel that does not sort the last row. In the following example you will see on the left side the original table and on the right side the table with the special order.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class SortFilterProxyModel: public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
public:
    using QSortFilterProxyModel::QSortFilterProxyModel;
    bool lessThan(const QModelIndex &left,
                  const QModelIndex &right) const
    {
        int row_max = std::max(left.row(), right.row());
        if(row_max >= sourceModel()->rowCount()-1)
            return left.row() < right.row();
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan(left, right);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QTableView *left_view = new QTableView;
    QTableView *right_view = new QTableView;
    QHBoxLayout *hlay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    hlay->addWidget(left_view);
    hlay->addWidget(right_view);
    QStandardItemModel model(12, 3);
    SortFilterProxyModel proxy;
    proxy.setSourceModel(&model);
    left_view->setModel(&model);
    right_view->setModel(&proxy);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dis(100.0, 200.0);
    for (int i=0; i< model.rowCount(); ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<model.columnCount(); ++j){
            QStandardItem *it = new QStandardItem;
            it->setData(dis(gen), Qt::DisplayRole);
            model.setItem(i, j, it);
        }
    }
    w.resize(640, 480);
    proxy.sort(2);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```